# Select() sometimes does not wait

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, chat, chatroom

I'm writing a chat program, and my receive function sometimes does not wait at all.. Here is the receiving code: The important parts are basically the first half, but i've added the whole function just in case. (Edit: the commenting is for myself, not notes to you guys reading! sorry!)

```
ReceiveStatus Server::Receive(PacketInternal*& packetInternalOut)
{
    fd_set fds ;
    int n ;
    struct timeval tv ;

    // Set up the file descriptor set.
    FD_ZERO(&fds) ;
    FD_SET(*p_socket, &fds) ;

    // Set up the struct timeval for the timeout.
    tv.tv_sec = NETWORKTIMEOUTSEC ;
    tv.tv_usec = NETWORKTIMEOUTUSEC ;

    // Wait until timeout or data received.
    n = select ( *p_socket, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv ) ;
    if ( n == 0)
    { 
        return ReceiveStatus::ReceiveTimeout;
    }
    else if( n == -1 )
    {
        return ReceiveStatus::ReceiveSocketError;   
    }

    //need to make this more flexible so it can support others
    sockaddr_in fromAddr;
    int flags = 0;
    int fromLength = sizeof(fromAddr);

    char dataIn[TOTALPACKETSIZE];
    int bytesIn = recvfrom(*p_socket, dataIn, TOTALPACKETSIZE, flags, (SOCKADDR*)&fromAddr, &fromLength);
    // Convert fromAddr into ip, port
    if(bytesIn == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        return ReceiveStatus::ReceiveSocketError;
    }
    if(bytesIn > 0)
    {
        memcpy(packetInternalOut,dataIn,bytesIn);
        return ReceiveStatus::ReceiveSuccessful;
    }
    else
    {
        return ReceiveStatus::ReceiveEmpty;
    }

}
```

Is there anything that could effect whether or not this works or doesn't work? my chat program can either be a server or a client. they both use this same code. The server, when waiting for a connection, sits on Select() for 100 seconds, as NETWORKTIMEOUTSEC = 100. But in the char program, whenever I want to send a message, i first send a transfer request, and then I wait for an acknowledgement (For the acknowledgement packet, i need to call receive again). Now this is the step that **does not wait**. my ReceiveAck function calls Receive(), and receive just runs straight over the entire code. I can test this by creating a client and no server. If i send a message where there is no server, it should wait 100 seconds for an acknowledgement, and then time out. But instead, as soon as i hit enter, it says it timed out.

i cant work out what would be making it skip this step. I have debugged my chat program in both its server and client states. The values of tv and fds are the same in both, yet the server will wait and the client wont...

Comment: I might be wrong but shouldn't it be `select(*p_socket + 1,.....)`??

Comment: Oh, I see Chrisaycock has already mentioned it.

Answer (score 4):

The first parameter to `select()` is *one greater than* the last socket. So you need:

```
n = select ( *p_socket + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv ) ;
```

Comment: The first parameter is the number of sockets that can fit in the set. To include socket number 10, the set must have room for 11 sockets in it -- 0 to 10.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - That is not quite correct.  On Unix, it's the first param to select is "nfds is the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1". On Windows, the parameter is ignored.

Comment: @selbie: That's advice for setting its value, and the minimum value that will work, but not what it actually *is*. It's badly-worded. There's no obligation on the caller to figure out which socket is the largest, add one to it, and pass it as the first parameter. You can safely pass the size of the file descriptor set if you want. [The standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/select.html) says, "The *nfds* argument specifies the range of file descriptors to be tested."

Comment: "The nfds argument specifies the range of file descriptors to be tested. The select() function tests file descriptors in the range of 0 to nfds-1."

Answer (score 0):

Select also returns early (i.e. without any of the sockets having data present) when your application is hit by a signal. So if your app uses a lot of usleep() and friends in a different thread, you might be in for a surprise.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause it to return -1 and set `errno` to `EINTR`?

Comment: true, but how many people check the return value?  I think the answer is "Not enough.".

Answer (score 0):

`select()` should always be used in a loop.  You must check its return for three conditions:

- `-1` (an error), which you must evaluate to determine if it is fatal.  `EINTR` is an example of a non-fatal error.
- a zero, in which case some *indeterminate* amount of time has passed and, if you care about how long its been, you need to check the time separately.
- A positive value, in which case you should check all of the flagged descriptors and act on them.

In all cases, you should check whether any other conditions exist which might make you want to exit the loop, such as how much time as actually passed.

Note that the first parameter to `select()` should generally be the constant `FD_SETSIZE`.  There is little to be gained in setting it to anything else.

Also note that just because you received a datagram doesn't mean you received the datagram you wanted.  You need a way to check that you did not get some random datagram that happened to be floating around on the network (it happens).  Along those lines, make sure `TOTALPACKETSIZE` is 65536, because that's theoretically (approximately) how big a random packet could be.